# Quickly insert an internal hyperlink in a Microsoft Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, shortcuts, hyperlink

When working on a word document having large number of bookmarks, inserting internal hyperlink using usual "Insert Hyperlink" dialog is laborious.

You need to manually search for the bookmark in the "Place in this document" expanded tree. This is a problem when you have large number of bookmarks. 
(The "Insert Hyperlink" dialog resets on subsequent insert links)

**Is there an alternate way or shortcut to quickly do this ?**

Comment: How would you tell Word which bookmark links to a reference? If you're looking for a shortcut, the most you could do is define a keyboard shortcut (through a macro) that opens the 'Insert Hyperlink' dialog. You'd still have to manually choose the bookmark that the reference links to

Answer (score 7):

1. Double-click the word or phrase you want to hyperlink.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
3. Paste or type in where you want that word or phrase to go (its hyperlink, e.g. http://www.whatever.com).

Comment: I had a few hundred links to dump in a doc. This tip made the difference between me making a deadline or not... I made it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the bookmark you can create the field yourself:

1. Type: `HYPERLINK \l “MyBookmark”` where MyBookmark is the bookmark
   name into the document. This is the field code of the hyperlink.
2. Highlight the text and press CTRL+F9. This creates the field using
   the highlighted field code.
3. While the cursor is still on the field press F9 to update it.

Depending on your system this will either be much easier or much harder compared with using the dialog but since it might help so I posted it anyway.

Comment: Is there any documentation from Microsoft for these kind of textual shortcuts?

Comment: @CodeBlend: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290938

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to quickly open the hyperlink dialog.

Other than that, there is no way for Word to know where you would like the hyperlink to be placed in the document or which one you would like to reference elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

On a mac running excel 2011, you can do this:

1. click on cell you want the hyperlink to land on. "Copy".
2. click on cell you want to hyperlink from. "Paste as Hyperlink".

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is to use the cross-reference function.  You will find this on the References tab in the Captions section.

Answer (score 1):

In the new MS Office 365 (which is very similar to Office 2016) the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.